# How to export result set as CSV from Aurora Postgres DB to AWS-S3?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

As part of my `Flask` and `Celery` application, I'm trying to move data from **AWS-Aurora Postgres DB** to **Redshift**.

I'll be running this application in **Kubernetes**.

My approach is to query the aurora **Postgres** database and write the result set to a CSV file which is saved on to an attached `volume` and then upload it to `S3` and then import the file into `Redshift`.

However, I came across another article which lets us directly upload the result set as a `CSV` file to `S3` instead of having an intermediate volume.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html

They've mentioned the usage of `OUTFILE` command. But it's mentioned about `MySQL`. But they haven't mentioned anything about `Postgres DB`.

Is it even possible to use the command on `Aurora Postgres DB` and export to `S3`.

Comment: Why are you reading the MySQL-specific documentation if you are using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Because I couldn't find any such thing related to Aurora Postgres DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to the database with psql, you can use the \copy command to export the output from any select statement to a csv:

https://codeburst.io/two-handy-examples-of-the-psql-copy-meta-command-2feaefd5dd90

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7651/postgres-client-copy-copy-command-doesnt-have-access-to-a-temporary-table

Comment: I was trying to use `SELECT * FROM .... OUTFILE ` command. The `\copy` command that is in the article that you've provided should be run on command line manually which is what I was not working on. I was using `psycopg2` library to connect and execute commands on the remote database.

Comment: psycopg2 offers copy_from, copy_to, and copy_expert which are its way of doing what "psql" does with `\copy`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Aurora runs on MySQL so you can use the `outfile` command. Did you even try running a query with `outfile`?